# position icon of ElevatedButton.icon to the right

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've got an elevated button with an icon where the icon is placed left to the text using `ElevatedButton.icon`. What I actually want is to place the icon to the right of the text. How can I do it
my code :

```dart
    ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        icon:Icon(icon,
          color: color != null ? color : null,
          size: getIconSize(),
        ),
        label: Text(label),
        style: buttonStyle);
```

How it looks :

[image]

what I want :

**Next ->**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use  `Directionality` widget. Make the direction `rtl`.

```dart
Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: ElevatedButton.icon(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
        ),
        label: Text("Test"),
     //.........
      ))
```

Now, you just need to add your style

[image]

Comment: But for internationalization to RTL languages, you would want the icon on the left, so you really want to use the direction opposite to the normal view direction. (Also you would want to reverse the arrow direction...)

Answer (score 6):

You could just use the regular `ElevatedButton` constructor and pass in a Row as its child, with your icon and text:

```
 ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        style: buttonStyle,
        child: Row(mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min,
children:
[Text(label),
SizedBox.square(dimension: 4),
Icon(icon,color: color != null ? color : null,size: getIconSize()),
]),)
```

[image: Sample result]